# Selecting maximum value row using documentum query language (dql)

Tags: documentum, documentum-dql

I have a few columns let's say

```
r_object_id, date, c, d, e, f
```

Now I want to have results such that only the object id row with maximum maximum dates remains

Eg: If the values are

```
R1, 29nov, c1,d1,e1,F1
R1, 30nov, c2,d2,e2,f2
R2, 20nov, c3,d3,e3,f3
R2, 25nov, c4,d4,e4,f4

The result should be 
R1, 30nov, c2,d2,e2,f2
R2, 25nov, c4,d4,e4,f4
```

I'm not able to use max with group by for this as the other columns are different and I need results in a way that all columns can be seen , is there a way this can be achieved using documentum query language (dql)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r_object_id, date, c, d, e, f 
FROM <table_name> 
ORDER BY date desc ENABLE (RETURN_TOP 2)
```

`ORDER BY` will do the work. For limiting number of returned rows use `ENABLE (RETURN_TOP N)`

Comment: This will give me all the rows , I just need 2 rows out of 4 in the result

Comment: answer adjusted